# Android Webview loading from cache only works perfectly in the second time

Tags: java, android, webview

I loaded web page with the following code:

```
    final String url  = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/webcache";
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(path);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(path);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

At first,I run it with network,and then I disconnect network in order to let it load from cache.But it only loads well in every two times.
just like this:
The first time:
[image]

The Second time:
[image]

(the third is same with the first,the fourth is same with the second....)
I found a similar questions on so: [WebView must be loaded twice to load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112715/webview-must-be-loaded-twice-to-load-correctly)
I have tried all the solutions under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112715/webview-must-be-loaded-twice-to-load-correctly) question,and even try to  disabled hardware acceleration,but didn't work ....

Any suggestions will be grateful.

Thanks in advance.(sorry with my trouble English ：) )

Comment: I would definitely like to see an answer on this question, because the linked question doesn't actually have a real answer. I believe there may be a bug in the stock webview / webviewclient.